# Select random row where condition apply effectvely

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of names with structure likes this :

```
id int(11) -Auto Increment PK
name varchar(20)
gender varchar(10)
taken tinyint - bool value
```

I want to get a random name of a single row where gender is say male and taken is false. How can I do that without slowing down ?

What comes to mind is, `SELECT` all the rows where `gender = male` and `taken = false`. Then use php's `rand(1, total_rows)` and use the name from that randomly generated record number for the array of results.

Or I can use, but `RAND()` is going to slow down the process (taken from other questions on stackoverflow)

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE (`long`='0' AND lat='0') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Get the total number of items that meet your conditions, then select one that is a random offset with a limit of 1

Comment: But is it actually slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the following approach:

1. select the id list that meet your criteria, like `SELECT id FROM table WHERE name=...`
2. choose an id randomly with php
3. fetch whole data with that id, like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=<id>`

This approach would maximize the query cache in MySQL. The query in step 3 has a great chance of hitting the same id, in which case query cache can accelerate database access. Further more, if caching like memcached or redis is used in the future, step 3 can also be taken care of by them, without even going to db.

Comment: Is retrieving a single column faster then retrieving all the columns ? Also is retrieving list of IDs is faster then retrieving names ? If that's the case, this looks like the best approach.

Comment: To be accurate, retrieving PK column only is faster than retrieving all columns because db won't read actual data, it only need to read from PK index. This applies to your 2nd question because retrieving names involves reading actual data from disk, which is way slower than reading from index only.  HOWEVER in your case, please make sure you have indices created for your `name` and `gender` columns because they are used as query criteria. Without indices on these columns, the query in step 1 will result a FULL_TABLE_SCAN which will significantly slow down the query.